# Why does the code in "view" folder show nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in "view" folder:

```
<h1><%= Time.now.to_s %></h1>
```

And it showed the time on the webpage.

When I type:

```
<h1><%= print "Hello world!" %></h1>
```

nothing shows.

Why?

This code is in the "view" folder as "say.html.erb"

Comment: Well you don't need `print` for a start. Other than that the code should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is for interacting with the console.

Just use:

```
<h1><%= "Hello world!" %></h1>
```

Or even better:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

Comment: what if I want to have some calculation??like x=8,y=6,print z=x+y

Comment: <%- x=8 %>
<%- y=6 %>
<%- z=x+y %>
<%= z %>

Comment: Don't do calculations like that in a view, do them in the controller, assign the result to a variable, and access the variable in the controller.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either, but just practice purposes, I wrote that.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the return value of `print` is `nil`.

```
print :foo
# => nil
```

Comment: so,what should I type in ruby language??

Comment: If it is a static string, then write it directly without Ruby evaluation.